# Calculate the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+2)}^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+6n^{2})}^{2}}\right)$

Tags: limits

I have to calculate the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+2)}^{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+4)}^{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+6)}^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+6n^{2}-2)}^{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+6n^{2})}^{2}}\right)$$

I tried to use Sandwich Theorem like this $$\frac{3n^{2}}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+6n^{2})}^{2}} \leq \Bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+2)}^{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+4)}^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+6n^{2}-2)}^{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+6n^{2})}^{2}}\Bigg) \leq \frac{3n^{2}}{\sqrt[3]{(8n^{3}+2)}^{2}}$$

And for result I got that limit is $\frac{3}{4}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of an overkill, but an alternative approach giving a bound on the rate  of convergence as well:

$$
S_{n}:=\sum_{i=1}^{3n^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\left(8n^{3}+2i\right)^{2}}}=\frac{1}{4n^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{3n^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac{2i}{8n^{3}}\right)^{2}}}
$$

By Taylor expansion, for small enough $x$:

$$
1-\frac{2}{3}x\leq\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{2/3}}\leq1-\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{5}{9}x^{2}
$$

Some double-checking if this really holds:
$$
1-\left(1+x\right)^{2}\left(1-\frac{2}{3}x\right)^{3}=\frac{1}{27}x^{2}\left(8x^{3}-20x^{2}-10x+45\right)
$$

This is positive for $1\geq x\geq0$ as $8x^{3}-20x^{2}-10x+45\geq45-30\geq15$.

$$
1-\left(1+x\right)^{2}\left(1-\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{5}{9}x^{2}\right)^{3}=-\frac{1}{729}x^{3}\left(125x^{5}-200x^{4}+440x^{3}+144x^{2}-270x+1080\right)
$$

This is negative for $1\geq x\geq0$, as $125x^{5}-200x^{4}+440x^{3}+144x^{2}-270x+1080\geq-200-270+1080>0$.

As $6n^2<8n^3$ (maximum of $i$ for a given $n$), these estimations hold for every $n$.
Using these approximations to bound the sum:

$$
S_{n,0}:=\frac{1}{4n^{2}}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{3n^{2}}1=\frac{3}{4}
$$

$$
S_{n,1}:=\frac{1}{4n^{2}}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\sum_{i=1}^{3n^{2}}\frac{2i}{8n^{3}}=\frac{1}{4n^{2}}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{3n^{2}+1}{4n}= \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)
$$

$$
S_{n,2}:=\frac{1}{4n^{2}}\cdot\frac{5}{9}\sum_{i=1}^{3n^{2}}\left(\frac{2i}{8n^{3}}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{4n^{2}}\cdot\frac{5}{9}\frac{\left(3n^{2}+1\right)\left(6n^{2}+1\right)}{48n^{4}}= \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^2}\right)
$$
Hence:
$$
\frac{3}{4}+S_{n,1}+S_{n,2}\geq S_{n}\geq\frac{3}{4}+S_{n,0}
$$
And the rate of the convergence is $\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

You could have done it a bit faster and get more than the limit using generalized harmonic numbers.

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{3n^2}\frac{1}{\left(8 n^3+2k\right)^{3/2}}=\frac 1{2\sqrt 2}\Bigg[H_{4 n^3+3 n^2}^{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}-H_{4
   n^3}^{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)} \Bigg]$$

Now, using the asymptotics
$$H_{p}^{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}=\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\frac 2{p^{1/2}}+\frac  1{2p^{3/2}}-\frac  1{8p^{5/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^{9/2}}\right)$$ apply it twice and continue with Taylor series to get
$$S_n=\frac{3}{16 \sqrt{2}\, n^{5/2}}\Bigg[1-\frac{9}{16 n}+\frac{45}{128 n^2}-\frac{1713}{4096
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) \Bigg]$$